# What is the best way to tag these strings using Regex Expressions?

Tags: regex, string, tags

```
#{config_name=Scene&sn={2}&field=name}

#{pos_x={3}&y={4}&z={5}&stage={6}&stageId={7}&content=Go Now&http=true&underline=true}

{{rescue_{1}_{2}_Rescue Now}}

#+\{.*?\}
```

I tried to use this expression but it didn't help

Comment: You can specify language where you will run these regex expressions

Answer (score 0):

My solution that will match either strings with '#' at start and multiple params inside the brackets, either anything inside double brackets (if this is what you want)

```
(#\{[a-zA-Z_]+=.*(&[a-zA-Z_]+=.*)*\})|(\{\{.*\}\})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either repeat matching the key=value pairs with an ampersand in between for the `#{....}` strings, or for the `{{...}}` strings match the curly's at the start and end where you would only match curly's in between that contain digits.

```
^(?:#{[^=&]+=[^=&]+(?:&[^=&\n]+=[^=&\n]+)*}|{{[^{}]*(?:{\d+}[^{}]*)*}})$
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/7j4x7Q/1).

Another bit broader match is to match the same key=value pairs, or match `{{...}}` from the start till the end of the string allowing any character in between:

```
^(?:{{.*}}|#{[^{}\n]*(?:{\d+}[^{}\n]*)*})
```

See another [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/chUlAg/1).